# Example of the topology which has a dense closed point and has non-empty proper closed subset which does not contain any closed point

Tags: general-topology

is there topology $X$ satisfying the following conditions ?

1. the set of closed point $H$ is a dense subset of $X$
2. there is non-empty proper closed subset $Z \subset X$ which does not contain any closed point

---

[My attempt]

I believe the $X$ exists but I can't take any example..

First, by condition 2, since   $ H \subset X \setminus Z $ so we know that $X \setminus Z $ is a dense open subset of $X$

Second, by condition 2, $X$ is not $T_1$ space because any singleton set of $T_1$ space is a closed subset.

I checked the zariski topology, the Sierpinski space, the overlapping interval topology , etc (the examples in wikipedia) ..
but they are not solutions.

Comment: In any example of the sort you're looking for, the set $H$ must be infinite. If $H$ were finite, then $H$ would be closed (finite union of closed sets), and since $H$ is dense in $X$, we would have $H=X$ so $Z$ would be empty.

Comment: In case you're interested, I modified my answer to give an example where the space $X$ is a $T_0$ space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=H\cup Z$ where $H$ is infinite, $|Z|\ge2$, and $H\cap Z=\emptyset$, with the topology $\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{H\setminus F:F\subseteq H,\ F\text{ finite}\}\cup\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq H,\ F\text{ finite}\}$.

$H$ is a dense subset of $X$, and every finite subset of $H$ is closed; $Z$ is closed but no nonempty proper subset of $Z$ is closed.

**P.S.** Here is an example where $X$ is a $T_0$ space.

Let $X=H\cup Z$ where $H$ and $Z$ are disjoint infinite sets, and let $\lt$ be a total ordering of $Z$ with no greatest element. Let $\tau$ be the collection of all sets $U\subseteq X$ satisfying the conditions:
(1) if $U\ne\emptyset$ then $H\setminus U$ is finite;
(2) if $a,b\in Z$, $a\lt b$, and $b\in U$, then $a\in U$.

Then $\tau$ is a $T_0$ topology on $X$; a singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$ (a "closed point") if and only if $x\in H$; the set $H$ of all closed points is an open dense subset of $X$; and $Z$ is a nonempty closed set containing no closed points.